# How to trigger event emitter when matautocomplete panel is opened

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to print to console 'hello' upon matautocomplete panel is open. How to do this?

This is what I have tried 
**template.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input class="selectCustomer" opened id="inputCustomer" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto"  [formControl]="customerFilterControl" [(ngModel)]="customerName">
  <mat-autocomplete dropdown-arrow="true" panelWidth ="450px" #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith] = "displayFn">
     <mat-option class="CustomerDropDown" *ngFor="let customer of filteredOptions | async"   [value] ="customer.AccountID +' '+'('+ customer.AccountName + ')'" (onSelectionChange)="onCustomerChange(customer)">
      {{customer.AccountID}} ({{customer.AccountName}})
     </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

According to matautocomplete document, I see this, I am not familiar how to use this for my requirement, can someone please help me?

@Output()
opened: EventEmitter

Event that is emitted when the autocomplete panel is opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Output EventEmitter is used to communicate between parent component and child component specifically to notify parent from child component , so in your case `mat-autocomplete` is a child component so you should add `opened` event inside the `mat-autocomplete` tag ex :

```
<mat-autocomplete (opened)="isOpened()" ...>
```

and inside your component (parent) declate `isOpened(){}` method to get fired when the autocomplete get opened and create object of the event emitter

```
  @Output() opened: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();
```

[Parent listen to child event](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)